# Authentication/Authorization in Spring Interceptor and web services

Tags: java, spring, web-services, interceptor

I have already managed to make my Web Services worked with Spring.
I now need to add authentication so not everyone can use my web services.
There are many classes and interfaces but I am not sure which one I could use.

What is the best approach for it? Does anyone have any good example I could see?
Really appreciate it.

Comment: Use Spring Security, it integrates nicely with Spring WebServices. Check http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/reference/html/security.html for more options and details.

Comment: Thanks Deinum, I have been through that. That's very useful indeed. But I really need an example which can gives me straight answer. I need to know which Class or Interface I need to extend or implement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you intend to have a simple BasicAuth authentication (just username and password), the following XML is enough secure your services, you don't need to extend/implement anything:

```
    <http auto-config="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/description*" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/wherever" />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="user1" password="password" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
                <user name="user2" password="password" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
```

**NOTE:** you need to add the appropriate Maven dependencies as well:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

You can play around with what actual roles, user and passwords you want to use.

**EDIT:** in case you don't use Maven, you have to manually download the JAR files and add them to your classpath wherever you keep your libraries. 
These are the links where you can download the JAR, look for the *Download (JAR)* button:

- [Spring Security Web](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-web/3.2.3.RELEASE)
- [Spring Secuirty Config](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-config/3.2.3.RELEASE)

> in which file, I should copy and paste the Simple Basic Auth you made for me?

You paste them in your **spring-config.xml** file

Comment: Gabriel,Thanks for the response. I don't have any Maven. All I have is web.xml, spring-config.xml (Spring configuration), my XSD files, Java files (created with XSD), my service java file, my service implementation java file and my endpoint. Till now everything works perfectly fine. So can I ignore the Maven? in which file, I should copy and paste the Simple Basic Auth you made for me? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Amin, I edited my response with instructions on how to use the Security configurations and add libraries